# Rendering Order of Angular Directives with templateURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following scenario, simplified in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyEr3/1744/)

I'm trying to run some code in the parent wizard element, **after** all steps in it rendered. in this context, console logs are generated as they should: 
1. step1.
2. step2.
3. wizard.

However, when i change the template of any step to a templateURL with an actual HTML, the order is getting messed up and i cannot figure out a way to make sure that functionality in wizard is running last.

I have tried this concept in the wizard directive but it still doesn't work for me.

```
$timeout(function () {
    //DOM has finished rendering
});
```

Is there a known solution for this?

Comment: not clear what problem is with order. [Works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eKwWzrvBsWHkiGUvwDJO?p=preview). Try to update and fork this demo to replicate your problem

Comment: Also...what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Generally, I am trying to initialize this JQuery plugin (https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps) by running $("#wizard").steps(); (which needs to be ran after all content is rendered). thing is. if i run it on the link function on the wizard, it runs BEFORE the rest of steps are rendered. and therefore doesn't initialize correctly.

Comment: In your sample, you can see how the wizard log is written to the console BEFORE the rest of the steps, whereas my need is for it to run LAST, after all of the steps were already rendered.

Comment: to do what though? you haven't mentioned what your main objective is

Comment: My rule of thumb with angular is, if I have to use jQuery, I'm doing it wrong. 99% of the time, angular has a solution for what you're doing because it is highly opinionated.

Comment: i don't have to use it, but this is a JQuery control that i like and seem to do the job that i need. and i don't find an angular alternative for it. I don't see why i should not use it.

Comment: What does that wizard plugin do that can't easily be done in angular? As far as I know all it does is provide a bit of navigation style and tracks steps which is very simple to do in a service. if it was me I would perhaps borrow the css for navigation and whip up a quick stepTrack service

Comment: yeah, all you'd need is a service that had stepTracker, your "wizard" directive has an button with ng-click="stepTracker.currentStep = stepTracker.currentStep + 1" and then each step just has a <div ng-if="stepTracker.currentStep === 1"  or two etc. easy peasy.

Comment: Also very simple to set up router to configure each step and store all data in a wizardData service. Use a route parameter to determine which template to render

Comment: ok maybe these solutions make more sense in this case. but still, what if this was not a simple wizard and had more complex functionality? this is why my question was abstracted initially. how can i check that all inner html is rendered?

Comment: The whole point of angular is to make "complex" functionality "easy". You have to change the normal way of thinking, which is to access the DOM. The way this is done is by 1) two-way binding and 2) nifty built-in directives like ng-if ng-class ng-click ng-repeat etc. Then just define your actions in js. I've written incredibly complex apps (charts, realtime analysis, quizes, geolocation) with 50,000 lines of code, all without depending on the state of HTML being rendered... and very, very limited use of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I made a jsfiddle with the answer. http://jsfiddle.net/KyEr3/1746/ However, I don't see why you would need to do this. Basically, you could have a service track the init count to ensure both directives have initialized. Watch the value of this tracker, and test it when it changes. Kazam.

Because services are singletons and persistent, you may want to reset the count to zero when the wizard directive initializes.

Here's the code:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service("initState", function(){
return{
    initCount:0,
  finishStep:function(){
    this.initCount++;
  }
}

});

myApp.directive("wizard",function(initState){
    return {
    link: function($scope){
        $scope.$watch(function(){
        return initState.initCount;
      }, function(){
      console.log('init count', initState.initCount );
        if( initState.initCount === 2){
            console.log('link on wizard');
        }
      })

    },
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<step-1></step-1><step-2></step-2>"
    }
});

myApp.directive("step1", function(initState){
    return {
    link: function(){
        console.log('link on step1');
      initState.finishStep();
    },
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<h1>Step1</h1>"
    }
});

myApp.directive("step2", function(initState){
    return {
    link: function(){
        console.log('link on step2');
       initState.finishStep();
    },
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<h1>Step2</h1>"
    }
});
```

Comment: this works, but i have an issue with this approach. since my number of steps may change, some may be added later, some may be removed. I'd hate to need to manage the initCount number for this (in this case "2"). I'd like this to be managed automatically based on the number of steps that are rendered.

Comment: truth is, you probably are doing it wrong. whatever it is you're doing (you haven't explained).

Comment: that being said, you could store a boolean called by the name of each directive or whatever and set it to true when the directive runs... but relying on cross-directive initialization is a workaround for a problem that likely has  a different solution.